# element.style.transform = translate() onScroll - Does not work

Tags: javascript, html, dom, transform, translate

I am trying to create a movement for individual letters, I did a function called **generateText** that creates the arrangements of `<h2>` with the class **.letters**.

Later I'd like to select those letters individually and translate them by using scrollY. For some reasons this isn't going to work.

The DeveloperTool/Elements show to me that the style changes to

```
 style="transform: translate(32px, 0px);"
```

Anyway, the elements don't move.

Does someone know why?

```
   function generateText(string){
      var text = t("#appearOne");
      var arr = string.split("");

      for(i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
      text.innerHTML += "<h2 class="+ " letter " +">"+arr[i]+"</h2>";
    }
    }    
    function moveText(id){
      window.onscroll = ()=>{
        var arr = document.querySelectorAll(".letter");
            for(i=0; i<arr.length;i++){
              arr[i].style = "transform:translate(0px ,"+scrollY/8+"px)"
            }
      }
}
```

Comment: And where would `yScroll` be coming from ?

Comment: Thanks for telling me. I had it changed to yScroll more up in the code. I changed it to normal scrollY in this example for clearer understanding.

Comment: And .... where is `scrollY` coming from ?

Comment: I do not understand the question. scrollY is a global variable on the window object. So it gives me the vertical scroll of the page.

Comment: SOLVED: For those who are interested. I solved the problem. I only needed to change the position of the element to position:absolute.